# Why is C++ backward compatibility important / necessary?

Tags: c++, c, programming-practices, c++11

As far as I understand it is a wide-spread opinion within the C++ community that certain features of C++ (including some features inherited directly from C), while still usable in themselves, do not fit well with the most recent C++ *best practices*.
For example, I read a comment on this site stating that new / delete should be avoided altogether in favor of smart pointers.

In view of this, I often wonder why backward compatibility with C and earlier C++ features is still important: to my knowledge there is no 100% compatibility, but most of C and C++ are contained in C++11 as a subset.

So, maybe it would be possible / make sense to drop earlier C++ features (e.g. the mentioned new / delete) from a future C++ standard so that it is impossible to use them in new code.

Existing code could still be maintained using the appropriate compiler. Interoperability between legacy and new code would be supported through separate compilation. One could continue to use the earlier standard or adopt the more recent one, only mixing the two would not be possible: a developer /team would have to **clearly choose** which programming style they want to use. The most flexible solution would be to have compiler options to switch on and off certain features (e.g. no new / delete allowed).

Would this be a viable strategy for encouraging the adoption of modern C++ practices? Are there technical problems (e.g. compiling existing templates,
ABI compatibility) that make such a change too difficult or even impossible?

Comment: You should read this famous article "Martin Headsets" http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/03/17.html from Joel about existing standards and the need for backward compatibility. He is writing about web browsers, but the same applies to C++ as well.

Comment: @Giorgio: and not to forget: what you suggest has already been tried with some success - non-backwards compatible compilers exist, they are called compilers for Java, C#, D, Go etc. In all those cases language designers had removed obsolete and "bad practice" features from the language.

Comment: I do not understand the downvote: I would appreciate suggestions as to how I can improve my question. BTW: this is NOT a C++ against C question, shall I make it clear in the main text of the question?

Comment: @jk, harald: To make it more precise, I do not want to state that C is obsolete in itself (and this is not the topic of this question) but maybe some of its features are obsolete as a subset of C++. But I am quite open about this too.

Comment: I think people downvoting the question should reread it carefully. It is an interesting question about the relationship between c and c++. @Giorgio you should rework your question by making it shorter and clearer, and avoid puting `C is an obsolete language` as your first bullet point. It is the first thing people will read and they will stop there.

Comment: @Simon: Thanks for the suggestions. I have reworked the question.

Comment: @Giorgio ok I think I'd agree that its commonly held that 'C with classes' is outdated, but not pure C

Comment: @jk: I was not arguing that C is outdated. My argument is: (1) the transition from C to C++ has already taken place and (2) many C++ developers say that they do not need / want certain C features -> would it make sense / be possible to drop those features from C++?

Comment: @DocBrown - There isn't a single method that Microsoft has removed from C# since its original release.  They might flag certain versions of a method as obsolete but C# 4.5 can compile any C#1.0 code without a problem.

Comment: @Giorgio - Wouldn't it be easier for those developers to simply not use those features?

Comment: "...wide-spread opinion within the C++ community that:"

"C is an obsolete language ..." 

Is there in the world a developer who uses a lot of C++ who doesn't under why C++ is compatible with most of C? Bjorn explains why this is in his seminal book.

" new and delete should be replaced by smart pointer primitives"  What gave you that idea?  New and delete are core operators in C++. Without them it wouldn't be C++.  Smart pointers are handy wrappers around new and delete, they are not replacements for them.  

Perhaps you've been hanging around too many Java programers, ;)

Comment: @Jim In Texas: Not really, I have been doing C++ for the last 4 years and I have constant discussions with colleagues because it is difficult to agree on a common style. I read about the idea that new / delete should be banned here on the forum and I understood that this is a new C++ guideline / best practice.

Comment: @Jim In Texas: Regarding C being obsolete, again, I often read comment from C++ developers stating this. So I got the impression that this is a wide-spread opinion among C++ programmers.

Comment: @Ramhound: you got me wrong - I meant, for example, that Java and C# are languages of the C/C++ family which are intentionally not backwards compatible to C or C++, intentionally leaving out features from C and C++ which are considered "bad practice".

Comment: @Doc Brown: I would add that while C# and Java took this step from the beginning, C++ took a more gradual approach, evolving over the years while keeping backward compatibility. Yet, (1) C++11 is very different from the original C++, and (2) has already a community of users adopting it. So dropping backward compatibility (or making it optional) should not be a big issue. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Giorgio: you would not write things like this if you had to keep a >=100K LOC application alive over several years. I have to, and I am really glad that C++ is as backwards compatible as it is. Using an "old compiler" for old code and a "new one" for new code would lead to so many impractical issues that we evenly could dump our product.

Comment: @jk.: C has been obsolete since 1989, when the Morris Worm proved that it was completely unsuitable for its primary intended purpose.  In a sane world, people still using it (or equally-insecure descendants such as C++ or Objective-C) today for any network-facing software, operating systems, or any software with any security requirements whatsoever, would be considered guilty of criminal negligence.

Comment: @Doc Brown: In your case I would simply not upgrade and keep using the standard in which the original code was written. Would that be an option? Anyway, what you are saying is exactly the kind of information that I was looking for with my question: technical, practical problems.

Comment: @Giorgio: the original code was written with an old 16 bit Borland C++ compiler - staying with that was really a no-go for us since it would have excluded us from Win64. The transition to a modern C++ compiler was really easy on the language side - thanks to backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Mason sorry, but what are you referring to? You are basically saying its insane to use windows or Unix, or almost all other operating systems? And that their creators should be prosecuted? :p

Comment: @Max: What I'm referring to is the Morris Worm, which used a buffer overflow (a bug caused by a design flaw in the C language which can't be fixed without rearchitecting the entire language and wreaking havoc on backwards compatibility) to break into computers across the Internet.  That should have been a warning sign.  How many billions of dollars in damages have been done since then, because people keep using C and C++ and leaving buffer vulnerabilities in software with security requirements? Darn straight their creators should be prosecuted for that!

Comment: @Mason Well it's true that buffer overflows are a risk, but even in C it can be helped by *not* writing outside your arrays. I'm not aware of any function that doesn't have a similar function that also takes a maximum number of bytes to write. Isn't that so? :p

Comment: @Max: That just moves the problem around. Then you need to make sure to get that parameter right, every time.  Bounds checking is something that needs to be implemented in the compiler, not in code, in order to get it right, and C can't do that.  You say it can theoretically be helped with better functions, but just look at all the buffer overflow vulnerabilities still being written (and still being patched) today.  It's something even experienced coders keep getting wrong over and over and over again, and we've known about it for more than 20 years now. When will we say "enough is enough"?

Comment: @Giorgio - "I have constant discussions with colleagues because it is difficult to agree on a common style".  Well, welcome to C++ development.  Because of its tremendous power and versatility there are as many preferred C++ coding styles as their are C++ developers.   I few this as a feature, but to others I can see it as a bug.  In the benevolent dictatorship that is Objective-C, for example, there is, as near as I can tell, pretty much One True Way of writing code.

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is to be able to turn off specific features for certain projects in your solution. Potentially, using this approach, you could also turn on features, like "all input parameters to a function are const by default" and other language altering options.

This might be hard to manage across large projects. So a best practice might be to only use these options on newly developed applications, or across all the projects in a new branch of an existing application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly your position (from the question and the comments under VJovic's answer), you'd have preferred instead of a mostly compatible C++11, a new language based (I'll call it NC++) on C++03 but source incompatible with it but linkable with it.

Here are some points to consider:

- it isn't possible to implement C++11 using existing C++03 ABI (compilers providers don't guarantee that linking code compiled in C++03 mode and in C++11 will works), and it is a safe guess that it would be the same for NC++. So you'd have to have new C++03 compilers targeting the NC++ ABI as well as NC++ compiler to have your idea implemented.
- you have the same problem with the standard library. You'd need a new implementation of the C++03 library able to be interoperable with your NC++ library.
- the transition from C to C++ can be smooth as C is mostly a C++ subset. When the C code takes advantage of C99 features not present in C++, the transition is less smooth. Notably shared headers have to be coded in the common subset of C++ and C which isn't natural if you want to take advantage of C99.  In your case, shared headers will have to be coded in the common subset of C++03 and NC++, which I fear will be impractical if your goal in NC++ is to take advantage of the possibility to break source code compatibility to have a "cleaner" language.

Comment: "A new language based (I'll call it NC++) on C++03 but source incompatible with it but linkable with it" Yes, that's what I had in mind. My idea is that such a language would be more suitable for promoting the current C++ best practices. I was wondering whether it would be practically feasible.

Comment: @Giorgio, I've pointed out some technical difficulties. There are others (for once, neither the implementation providers nor the standardization committee desire to impose their view of stylistic issues; they consider that the C++ community is wide and varied enough that doing so would get the opposition of a significant portion of it).

Comment: I understand. Dropping compatibility could split the community while the current solution tries to keep it together.

Comment: @Giorgio - It doesn't "try" to keep it together it does.  By making sure code written 20 years ago still works even if the C++11 compiler is used it means code the works simply does.  Besides it takes a much longer time for the compilers to support everything the language specifications say it should support.  There are many features that even TODAY that exst in C++ 03 and likely the revision before that still are not supported.

Answer (score 6):

Bjarne Stroustrup wanted to build a useful language based on C because it was

1. Already popular within s/w community
2. Supported low level programming as well as some high level features
3. Lots of code was already written in C

There was no plans to have aggressive marketing budget to make C++ popular on its own   as an individual language.
Instead of reinventing the wheel and introducing new syntax, Stroustrup chosen to build the new language on existing base itself (Like C was developed based on earlier language).

C++ is not fully backward compatible with C, wherever it's needed it has drawn a line. e.g.

- unsafe implicit typecasting is not allowed C++
- `inline`, `enum` and `const` were introduced with C++ and later
  adopted by C

Answer (score 5):

> Are there conceptual reasons or technical problems (e.g. compiling existing templates) that make such a change undesirable or even impossible?

Some features are deprecated, and you get a warning (with appropriate error checking level), and if you enable option that turns warnings into errors, you get the desired effect.

Now imagine when lots of features would be removed, or changed drastically. That would make lots of programs not compiling. For large projects that is unacceptable. Who would go over 300kLOC-2MLOC code to fix all failures?

With backward compability, upgrading the compiler is much simpler. You still have to fix some code, but number of failures is acceptable.

---

To your edit :

How you compile/link your application, depends on the build system.

If you use makefiles, it is fairly simple (not so simple in complex systems), to add new rules to build separate libraries. c code would be compiled using gcc, c++ code using specific version of g++, and new c++11 code compiled (again) with possible different g++ version, into separate shared libraries. The final application would then link to those libraries. Off course, you have to make sure that all compilers are using the same [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

Comment: *Who would go over 300kLOC-2MLOC code to fix all failures?* Not that it was fun, but I've done those types of changes.

Comment: One could imagine that some features are deprecated for a while (like 5 years) and then are dropped altogether. Anyway, I was suggesting that one uses an old compiler for legacy code and the new compiler for new code.

Comment: @Justin My colleagues done it as well when we upgraded compiler. Now imagine having several times more errors (as suggested in the question).

Comment: @Giorgio It's possible, if ABI was preserved between compiler versions, which might not be the case.

Comment: @VJovic: This is exactly the topic of my questions: what would be the technical problems involved. E.g. what features are required to preserve ABI compatibility.

Comment: @VJovic I'd go along with the changes… if I *agreed* with them. As an example - Bjarne wanted to remove C casts when C++ casts were introduced. That's a change I have made over a large codebase (happily, in retrospect). Unfortunately, I can't say I would agree with any/all changes. Superseding features certainly would be a pain to manage across multiple compilers/platforms.

Comment: Well, like you have .c and .cpp files, you could have .c, .cpp, and .c11 files, and let the compiler / build system pick the default language to be used with each file type. I have worked with mixed C, C++ projects and I did not encounter big problems.

Comment: @Giorgio But you didn't write it in your question. And that depends on the compiler. btw the standard doesn't say how to name c++ files. People usually name them `.c` for c files, and hpp,h,hxx for c++ headers, and cpp,cxx,c++ for c++ source files. If you are using makefile, you can add rules to compile `.c`,`.c11` and `.cpp` files differently. That depends on the build system you are using

Comment: I spoke about separate compilation. I will write it explicitly. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Giorgo, most production code live a _LOT_ longer than 5 years.  Most business cases do not warrant upgrading if the compiler is not backward compatible.

Comment: I thought about 5 year as the time you need to **stop using** old features in new code. My idea is that you maintain legacy code using the old compiler.

Comment: @Giorgio That is called "code cleanup" or "code refactoring". Normal companies do that :)

Comment: Refactoring means changing existing code, I was referring to new code.

Comment: +1: "If you enable option that turns warnings into errors, you get the desired effect.": I think this is an acceptable trade-off.

Comment: @Giorgio - Why would somebody stop using code after only 5 years if it still works?  Unless there is a reason to change it, it should remain the same, it sounds like you are part of this new breed of programmer who doesn't see the worth of proven leagcy code.

Comment: @Ramhound: On the contrary, I believe that legacy code is very important and should not be touched unless you need to fix bugs (the open / closed principle). Legacy code written in C++03 should still be used and stay as it is. It should not incorporate C++11 features. On the other hand, **new** code can / should be written in C++11.

Comment: What I meant with the 5-year example was the following. Suppose that a feature is deprecated. You know that in 5 years from now it will be made obsolete. So you stop using that feature when you are writing new code, because you know that in 5 years-time, compilers will not accept it. By the time the feature becomes obsolete, it will only be contained in code that is at least 5 years old and that should be changed only in case of a bug fix.

Answer (score 4):

You would effectively be talking about defining an entire new language- which is what's already happening with the numerous proposed C++ replacements over the years. I think that it's telling that none of them have actually succeeded in replacing C++.

Comment: I was not thinking about developing a successor to C++ that should replace C++. Rather, I was thinking about keeping the current C++ semantics and syntax and removing features that are no longer considered good practices or do not add any extra functionality. E.g. removing the struct keyword, discouraging macros in favour of constants and const expr, and so on.

Comment: @Giorgio - There being support for those features adds no additional overhead to your program once you compile it.  What do you care if it takes longer to compile?

Comment: @Giorgio: Removing all the redundant C features, and adding some of the new toys we could have if we didn't have to have them, would be equivalent to defining a new language.

Comment: @Ramhound: My problem is that I work in a project with more than 40 developers. Some use C-like style, some 1990-C++ style, some use more modern C++ style, and some are moving to C++11. Our code is like a bazaar and having written coding guidelines does not seem to help.

Comment: Our experience is that many developers will not follow certain restrictions unless they are imposed by the compiler and the team is too big to control each individual developer.

Comment: @DeadMG: But C++11 is already a different language wrt to 1990-C++. I often get the impression that dropping backward compatibility would only mean recognizing a process that has already taken place. Or maybe we have to wait until C++15, but I think we are close. Just MHO.

Comment: @Giorgio get an automatic style checking tool?

Comment: @MarkJ: The topic of this question was "What are the technical and non technical difficulties with breaking backward compatibility" not "What are viable alternatives to breaking backward compatibility". I know there are alternatives but this is not the topic of the question.

Comment: @Giorgio: The Standard will never, ever, drop backwards compatibility in significant ways. The only way to achieve this is to migrate to a new language. Your problem is irrelevant to this fact.

Comment: @Giorgio *Your question*: why can't the standard committee do X (in order to solve my problem A?) *My comment*: other answers show there are many drawbacks to doing X: and there are much better solutions to problem A anyway. IMHO I am on topic

Answer (score 1):

Both of your premises are wrong. Smart pointers are a performance-hit, and C is far from obsolete: Windows and UNIX system calls are defined in terms of C.  In fact, just about every OS in wide use today, except Symbian, uses C interfaces.  So if you want to have a language that supports system-level programming, you can't get away from new, delete, raw pointers and all of the things that you dogmatically believe are bad.

Comment: Can you read the first line of my question carefully, please? And the comments below the question?

Comment: Smart pointers are not a performance hit when used appropriately at all. And C *is* obsolete- for a start, the fact that people use C interfaces but nobody actually calls them from C doesn't make C not obsolete, and secondly, they're *binary* interfaces defined by the OS. They're simply natively expressed from C, but you hardly have to be using C to use them, so what makes them "C" interfaces escapes me.

Comment: @DeadMG:  _Nobody?_

Comment: @DeadMG PostgreSQL, Linux/*BSD kernels, ghostscript, and a bunch of other software being actively developed in C. Obsolete? Right. And "appropriately" is exactly the problem with smart pointers. Memory management is not a problem either, if raw pointers are used appropriately. Point being?

Comment: @zvrba - Don't worry...I entirely agree with you.

Comment: @DeadMG - "so what makes them "C" interfaces escapes me".  You are technically correct, it's all just bits in the end.  But having had to call into the Win32 API using Java and Delphi at times, it's a royal PIA to get the function parameters and return types to match up with the types used in other languages.  APIs like Win32 are just much easier to use when you talk to them in the same language their interface was written in.

Comment: The reason we still need operators `new` and `delete` even in the light of smart pointers is not so much a performance issue (In fact, using `std::unique_ptr` has practically zero overhead compared to direct use of `new` and `delete`.) but that without those fundamental operators, it would be *impossible to implement* smart pointers.  Your coding standard might have good reasons to discourage direct use of `new` and `delete` but that doesn't mean they should be removed from the *language*.

Answer (score 0):

I think Bjarne's view as of late has been that C and C++ should have been unified as a single language. I think that this could imply that his view is that C++ should be a replacement for C, and as such compatibility with C is important in such view.